# Check if all JComboBoxes have something selected any indexes (Other than index 0)

Tags: java, swing, for-loop, jcombobox

```
I have this code sample. 

    JComboBox[] set = {jComboBox1, jComboBox2, jComboBox3};        
        for (int i = 0; i < set.length; i++) {

            JComboBox boxes = set[i];
            int index = boxes.getSelectedIndex();

            if (index == 0) {    

                System.out.println("Not every JcomboBox has something selected");                    
                continue;

            } else {

                System.out.println("Every combobox has selected something"); 

            }
```

I know every time the `for loop` runs, it checks for each `JComboBox`'s selected values. if at least one `JComboBox` has selected something (all other indexes except 0) it won't execute the `if` statement hence it goes to `else` statement. **But I need print -*Every combobox has selected something*-** statement, if and only if **all of `JComboBoxes` have selected something**(any indexes other than index 0) but not **any of them has selected something**(i.e any indexes other than 0)

Can anyone please help me with this???

Comment: Work out the logic on paper first. Hint: you'll need a variable *before* the for loop that is used within the for loop.

Comment: Thanks you very much Sir for the hint :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use a `flag` variable.

```
boolean allSelected = true;  //Initially set it to true which indicates that all selected values are other than 0
for (int i = 0; i < set.length; i++) {

    JComboBox boxes = set[i];
    int index = boxes.getSelectedIndex();

    if (index == 0) {    
        allSelected = false;  //If index is 0, make it false
    }
} 

if(allSelected)
{
    System.out.println("Every combobox has selected something"); 
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Not every JcomboBox has something selected"); 
}
```